# Numbers stored as text - when converted to numbers, digits disappear

Tags: excel

I have a column of data with numbers stored in text.

The numbers look like this: 735999114002665788

If I select any cell in this column and refer to it with the function =value(), the number shows up as 735999114002665000.

As you can see the last three digits are 0. This happens all the time with numbers this long - but NOT with numbers containing less digits.

Am I trying to convert a number that's too large or what's up? Please help! I've tried every form of text-to-number method with identical results :(

Comment: Duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/437764/why-is-excel-truncating-my-16-digit-numbers

Comment: Excel only allows a maximum of 15 digits of precision in each cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel's number precision is 15 digits, which is why you're losing the last three digits when converting your 18 character string

---

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=Excel_2016-2013

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excel only allows a maximum of 15 digits of precision for each number in a cell.  The reason why this number:

```
735999114002665788
```

becomes this:

```
735999114002665000
```

is because Excel is choosing to retain the 15 most significant digits in the number.  This means that the ones, tens, and thousands digits are being tossed out.

By the way, this question has been asked before on SuperUser, and you can read about it here:

**https://superuser.com/questions/437764/why-is-excel-truncating-my-16-digit-numbers**